# Javascript while loop over ElementIds from DOM until first empty Element

Tags: javascript, while-loop, getelementbyid

Easy task i guess but i am new to this and am stuck. I want to iterate through some ElementIds of a webpage to extract the text within.

The ElementIds i am looking for are like this:

"p000", "p001", "p002", etc. (I guess it would go until "p999")

This is what i have so far.

```
var totalText=[]
while(text===""):
    var text=document.getElementById("p0003");
    totalText.push(text);
}
```

Now i would like to iterate through the ElementIds as described and stop as soon as text is empty which means there is no Element "p091" anymore and the loop stops and does not continue until "p999".

Comment: Where are the IDs of your elements stored (so you can iterate over them) - and what kind of elements are those? Span?

Comment: Add a common class to all your elements (p000 through to p999). Then use `document.getElementsByClassName()`. There is no benefit in querying the DOM multiple times when you can just use a class.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea Nick. Sorry i am new to this. How would i create such a class?

Comment: Answered Take A Look! @Mauritius

Comment: @Mauritius I've added an answer which explains the class approach in more detail. You can add a `class` attribute to your elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to each element (p000 through to p999) by adding the `class` attribute to all of them. Then use `document.getElementsByClassName()`. Querying the DOM is an expensive operation, so doing it a minimal amount of times is often a good idea. Also, `document.getElementsByClassName()` does the logic you're after, so there is no need to re-invent the wheel.

Here an example:

```js
var paragraphs = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('info-para'));
console.log(paragraphs);
```

```html
<p class="info-para" id="p0">0</p>
<p class="info-para" id="p1">1</p>
<p class="info-para" id="p2">2</p>
<p class="info-para" id="p3">3</p>
<p class="info-para" id="p4">4</p>
```

*Note*: Above, I have used a method called [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), which returns an array given an *array-like* collection. That's because `getElementsByClassName()` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is *like* an array, but not quite. So, in order to turn the HTMLCollection into an actual array you can use `Array.from()`.

**EDIT**:

In order to get an array of strings you can loop through the array you retrieved, and get the `innerText` of each element, and `.push()` that into a new array like so:

```js
var paragraphs = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('info-para'));

var texts = [];

for(var elem of paragraphs) { // loop through each element in paragraphs array
  texts.push(elem.innerText); // get the text of the current element, and push it to the texts array
}
console.log(texts);
console.log(texts.join(', '));
console.log(paragraphs);
```

```html
<p class="info-para" id="p0">0</p>
<p class="info-para" id="p1">1</p>
<p class="info-para" id="p2">2</p>
<p class="info-para" id="p3">3</p>
<p class="info-para" id="p4">4</p>
```

Once you become more comfortable with JS, you can write the code above more elegantly by providing a mapping method to the [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method and using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like so:

```js
const texts = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('info-para'), ({innerText}) => innerText);
console.log(texts);
```

```html
<p class="info-para" id="p0">0</p>
<p class="info-para" id="p1">1</p>
<p class="info-para" id="p2">2</p>
<p class="info-para" id="p3">3</p>
<p class="info-para" id="p4">4</p>
```

Comment: okay now i got it! it is true that all "p"'s have the same class and i just need to call the DOM once! Thanks a lot!

Comment: one last question. It somehow gives me back undefined when i do alert(paragraphs.innerText). How do i get the actual String?

Comment: But this isn't OP want, I know that he or she accepted your answer but he or she wants to get text of that div. Your answer returning an array.

Comment: @Mauritius do you want an array of strings (eg: ['0', '1', '2', ...]?

Comment: Array of Strings or just an entire huge string. Both fine

Comment: @Mauritius I've edited my answer to include an array of strings (I've also added a version using `.join(', ')` which converts the array into one big string separated by commas).

Comment: thanks @NickParsons! And thanks for your hint with the Class!

Comment: @AhmedAli I see now. I've updated my code. Also, you should use `innerText` (or `textContent`) when retrieving text from an element which is not HTML

Answer (score 1):

This will help just get all elements and loop through them!

```js
var arrayofelements = [];
function getElements(){
  var lenght=document.getElementsByTagName("div").length;
    for(var a = 0;a <= lenght; a++){   
      if(a == 0){
        a = "000";
      }
      else if(a <= 9){
        a = "00"+a;
      }
      else if(a => 10 && a < 99){
        a = "0"+a;
      }
      var text = document.getElementById("p"+a);
      if(text == undefined || text == null){
       return;
      }  
      arrayofelements.push(text.innerHTML);
    }
}
getElements();
arrayofelements.forEach(foreachfunc);
function foreachfunc(item,index){
  document.write("Array Data:   "+item);
}
```

```html
<div id="p000">0</div>
<div id="p001">1</div>
<div id="p002">2</div>
<div id="p003">3</div>
<div id="p004">4</div>
<div id="p005">5</div>
<div id="p006">6</div>
<div id="p007">7</div>
<div id="p008">8</div>
<div id="p009">9</div>
<div id="p010">10</div>
<div id="p011">11</div>
<div id="p012">12</div>
<div id="p013">13</div>
<div id="p014">14</div>
<div id="p015">15</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help @Ahmed! Seems to work well but I don't know how to add the missing zeros to your solution, so that it is e.g. "p001" , "p025", ...

Answer (score 1):

```js
var totalText = [];
var num = 2;
var text = document.getElementById("p001").innerHTML;
while (!(text === "")) {
  totalText.push(text);
  var str = "" + num;
  str = str.padStart(3, "0");
  text = document.getElementById("p" + str).innerHTML;
  if (text === "" || text === undefined || text === null) break;
  num++;
}
console.log(totalText);
```

```html
<div id="p001">1</div>
<div id="p002">2</div>
<div id="p003">3</div>
<div id="p004">4</div>
<div id="p005"></div>
<div id="p006"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for an id  that starts with a string and loop on those, breaking when the first empty text is found.  I added a class to illustrate the found one.  This relies on the DOM sequence for "first" here.

```js
var foundText=[];
var allPIdElements = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="p"]');
for (let el = 0; el < allPIdElements.length; el++) {
  let item =allPIdElements[el];
  let t = item.innerText;
  foundText.push( t );
  if (t == '') {
    item.classList.add('found');
    foundText.pop();// remove empty
    break;
  }
}
console.log(foundText);
```

```css
*[id^="p"] {
  border: solid 1px #777777;
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.found {
  border: #77DD77 solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="p001">clear</div>
<div id="p002">tear</div>
<p id="p003">watch</p>
<div id="p004">goat</div>
<div id="p005"></div>
<p id="p06"></p>
<div id="p026"></div>
<p id="p095">cheer</p>
<p id="p096">cheer</p>
<p id="p999">cheer</p>
```